# What happens to spacetime in a universe with no clocks?

Tags: cosmology, photons, spacetime, universe

For example, in the far future when all matter has been absorbed into BHs which have evaporated leaving only photons.

Comment: If a tree falls in the woods and no one is around, does it still make a noise?

Comment: @Neil Penrose, in his Conformal Universe theory would argue differently

Comment: All matter will be absorbed into BHs?

Comment: @Kyle possibly he means the last era before heat death

Comment: @KyleKanos More generally, in a universe with only photons, for whatever reason

Comment: I'm unclear on what kind of an answer you are looking for. As worded, the question reads much like those from newbies without any real physics background looking for some gee-whiz response. Now, I know that does not describe you at all. Could you flesh this out a little bit more?

Comment: @JonCuster It stems from claims made by Penrose in his "Conformal Cyclic Universe" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_cyclic_cosmology

Comment: In that case, I might suggest adding the background, and some words on what you are actually wondering about, to the question to clarify that it really has to do with a specific physics model. It will clear up a lot of confusion. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @JonCuster The actual question revolves around "what is a clock in quantum gravity" and specifically in the Penrose model. Given so little interest in related questions I have posted it's probably better for me to go direct to Penrose

Comment: Well, I suspect that a concise question around 'what is a clock in quantum gravity within Penrose's theory really mean' would attract more of the right kind of attention. Not that I know anything about that at all... The phrasing does count for something.

Comment: Good News: Here is a very recent paper which I found interesting to share with everyone: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.05449v1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As of now, we are not 100% sure of the destiny our Universe will choose in distant future. We don't know if this expansion will ever come to a halt or will ever go back into a crunch. 'Clocks' are embedded in the Nature of our Universe *as it is* and they will *continue to work* so long as we are *expanding* (just with different rates.) Blackholes are only *part* of this whole *system,* and hence inside them having 'clocks' stopped working, doesn't necessarily mean that other 'clocks' will follow suit. It could be just that evaporation of Blackholes is well before all the matter would have the chance to be absorbed by them which I think will never happen. We have clear indications that we are missing some considerable amount of Dark Matter (in an implied DM halos vs simulated DM halos mass functions) which actually does not have to follow the matter distribution in the cosmological webs. Uniting together these DM halos can actually form bound/virilized system where some of those photons can be trapped forever and produce a completely different physical processes. So, I think there is not much BHs in Universe to be able to 'eat' *all* the DM and make the case for the dispute.